# pdf.js - get data of modified pdf file

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

I'm using the pdf.js (v3.10.111) stable version (for modern browsers) from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download .

I'm able to load a pdf file and make graphical modification on it, and save the modified file onto my desktop. The code for this is the following:

. However, my goal would be to save the file back to the server. I'm not really aware how I can get the data of the modified file with Javascript / Jquery. How can I do that?

=====

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="build/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="build/pdf.worker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pdf-container"></div>
<iframe id="pdf-js-viewer" src="web/viewer.html?file=a.pdf" title="webviewer" frameborder="0" width="1024" height="1024"></iframe>
<button id="downloadPdfButton">Download PDF</button>
<div id="pdf-data-container"></div> <!-- The <div> to display the PDF binary data -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let pdfDocument = null;
        let editedPdfData = null; // To store edited PDF data

        const pdfUrl = 'a.pdf';

        pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfUrl).promise.then(function (pdfDoc) {
            pdfDocument = pdfDoc;

            $('#downloadPdfButton').click(function () {
                if (pdfDocument) {
                    // Check if editedPdfData is available, if not, use the original PDF data
                    if (editedPdfData) {
                        // Use the edited PDF data
                        displayEditedPdfData();
                    } else {
                        // Get the PDF blob data
                        pdfDocument.getData().then(function (data) {
                            // Create a Blob from the binary PDF data
                            const pdfBlob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                            // Create a URL for the Blob
                            const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);

                            // Display the original PDF binary data in the div
                            displayPdfData(pdfUrl);
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('PDF not loaded.');
                }
            });
        });

        // Function to display PDF data in the div
        function displayPdfData(dataUrl) {
            const pdfDataContainer = document.getElementById('pdf-data-container');
            pdfDataContainer.innerHTML = `<object data="${dataUrl}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px"></object>`;
        }

        // Function to display edited PDF data in the div
        function displayEditedPdfData() {
            if (editedPdfData) {
                // Create a Blob from the edited PDF data
                const editedPdfBlob = new Blob([editedPdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                // Create a URL for the Blob
                const editedPdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(editedPdfBlob);

                // Display the edited PDF binary data in the div
                displayPdfData(editedPdfUrl);
            }
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

=====

which is almost good. The only problem that it displays the original pdf, and not the edited one. I'd like to display the edited pdf in the div. I'd like to get that binary data.

Comment: "clent gets doc" - yes, that what I'd like to get, however, I don't know how.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do the same thing myself